# Clickable only 4 textview from 5 textview from listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Before I ask here, I already search and found an answer use this :

```
long viewId = view.getId();
```

but when I use that on my code, it is still click whole listview row rather click the textview that I want to click. Here is my code after implement that answer :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        long viewId = view.getId();
        if (viewId == R.id.masterclass_name) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "masterclass_name clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_popup_pesan_kelas);
            pesan_kelas = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pesan_kelas);
            sukses = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sukses);
            studio_name = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.studio_name);
            mohon_hadir = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mohon_hadir);
            booking_number = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.booking_number);
            indentitas_resmi = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.indentitas_resmi);
            bookbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bookbutton);
            selesaibutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.selesaibutton);
            bookbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pesan_kelas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sukses.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bookbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    selesaibutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mohon_hadir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    booking_number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    indentitas_resmi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            selesaibutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            closedialog = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeDialog);
            closedialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            studio_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StudioDetail.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        } else if (viewId == R.id.studio_nama) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "studio_nama clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, StudioDetail.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (viewId == R.id.trainer_name) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "trainer_name clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (viewId == R.id.area) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "area clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            CariKelasAdapter carikelas = (CariKelasAdapter) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), carikelas.getMasterclass_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, checkin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

the textview that I want to click has id : masterclass_name, studio_nama, trainer_name, area. There is another one textview id but I don't want that id can be clicked. So only 4 textview of 5 textview that can be clicked.

Each (from 4) textview will redirect to different result, example: one will show dialog, other redirect to another activity class.

Whats wrong with my code (why that answer did not work on my code)? How/what is the correct code to make that 4 textview become clickable?

For information, here is my adapter getView() :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.image_carikelas = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_carikelas);
        holder.masterclass_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.masterclass_name);
        holder.studio_nama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.studio_nama);
        holder.trainer_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trainer_name);
        holder.area = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.area);
        holder.facility = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.facility);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    //holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.promo_1);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.image_carikelas).execute(kelasList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.masterclass_name.setText(kelasList.get(position).getName());
    holder.studio_nama.setText(kelasList.get(position).getStudio_nama());
    holder.trainer_name.setText("Trainer: " + kelasList.get(position).getTrainer_name());
    holder.area.setText("Area: " + kelasList.get(position).getArea());
    holder.facility.setText("Facility: " + kelasList.get(position).getFacility());
    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use setOnItemClickListener at all. That's for clicking the whole item in the ListView.

You should create 4 OnClickListeners for the 4 textviews, and in getView() of your adapter, use setOnClickListener to link the 4 textviews to those OnClickListeners.

And usually you should set the item position as the tag of each textview, so in OnClickListener you can know which item it getting clicked by view.getTag()

Example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private MyActivity mActivity

    public MyAdapter(MyActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (int)v.getTag();
            // do stuff based on position or kelasList.get(position)
            // you can call mActivity.startActivity() if you need
        }
    };
    // similar for listener2,3,4

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.image_carikelas = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_carikelas);
            holder.masterclass_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.masterclass_name);
            holder.studio_nama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.studio_nama);
            holder.trainer_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trainer_name);
            holder.area = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.area);
            holder.facility = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.facility);

            // set OnClickListeners
            holder.studio_nama.setOnClickListener(listener1);
            holder.trainer_name.setOnClickListener(listener2);
            holder.area.setOnClickListener(listener3);
            holder.facility.setOnClickListener(listener4);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        //holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.promo_1);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.image_carikelas).execute(kelasList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.masterclass_name.setText(kelasList.get(position).getName());
        holder.studio_nama.setText(kelasList.get(position).getStudio_nama());
        holder.trainer_name.setText("Trainer: " + kelasList.get(position).getTrainer_name());
        holder.area.setText("Area: " + kelasList.get(position).getArea());
        holder.facility.setText("Facility: " + kelasList.get(position).getFacility());

        // set tags
        holder.studio_nama.setTag(position);
        holder.trainer_name.setTag(position);
        holder.area.setTag(position);
        holder.facility.setTag(position);
        return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: so setOnItemClickListener (on listview) change to? If I put setOnClickListener on getView() in adapter, how to redirect it to another activity or appear a dialog?

Comment: You can pass in the activity as a parameter of the adapter's constructor, and then use it when you need a context in the adapter.

Comment: could you show it as code because I did not understand.

Comment: cannot resolve method setonclicklistener(android.view.view.onclicklistener) on holder.studio_nama.setOnCickListener(listener1);

Comment: Sorry those were typos, should be .setOnClickListener, not .setOnCickListener. Fixed it.

Comment: how to know context in adapter? on super(context);

Comment: Please ignore that line, I deleted it.

Comment: so listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() change to?

Comment: Just delete that, you don't need it at all.